# I am trying to make an inventory management system using React. I am using axios to get and post to an API but request is failing with status code 429

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, mern

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Create() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  console.log(name);
  console.log(category);
  console.log(price);

  const sendData = () => {
    axios.post("https://63609f7caf66cc87dc1754b9.mockapi.io/IVMS", {
      name,
      category,
      price
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Product name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="exampleInputEmail1"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Product name"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category">Category</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="exampleInputPassword1"
            placeholder="Category"
            onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="exampleInputPassword1"
            placeholder="Price"
            onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={sendData}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Create;
```

This is the file that is posting data to the API. Even when I'm not sending any requests, it says too "too many requests".

I tried to make the user input values in the form and display them in a table underneath the form. It's working but it fails saying too many requests(429).

Answer (score 0):

try  `const sendData = () => {}` to `function sendData(){}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck